# Vuetify shows weird icons

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

It happens sometimes when I go next page and then come back previous page through url, icons become weird like O symbols and it happen with selects, buttons and components which have icons. I changed version of vuetify to 3.4.0 and mdi to 7.1.96 but nothing changed.
[image: shows normal]
[image: shows weird]
[image: even in selects it happens]
[image: button]

```
/**
 * plugins/vuetify.ts
 *
 * Framework documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com`
 */

// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Composables
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          error: '#F90808',
          info: '#339ef3',
          primary: '#1867C0',
          secondary: '#5CBBF6',
          success: '#4ae531'
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

here is my vuetify config

I tried to selve it through changing version but couldn't help. Icons should be displayed as usual not like O etc. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you add more info on your vuetify icons configuration?

Comment: added but nothing unusual

Comment: You can check if you have issues downloading the font file for the icons. the font file is show in the css file. It is something like materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2

Comment: You could try using the [svg icons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#mdi-js-svg)

Comment: I use the same setup and have seen these weird icons too more than once.  I only use materialdesignicons. I haven't been able to replicate it. It's at random times.

Comment: @yoduh couldn't help